# In case of SSL offloading, will a server behind Load balancer need its own SSL certificate?

Tags: ssl

I have an SSL Offloading scenario, so will a server behind Load balancer need its own SSL certificate?

And also we to generate CSR for load balancer URL to HTTPS from client to LB

Answer (score 0):

If you are offloading SSL to the load balancer, it is the load balancer that terminates the SSL connection and passes non-SSL-ed traffic back to the server. You need the cert only on the LB.

So no, you no longer need an SSL certificate or even SSL capability on the server itself.

Client <--https--> LB <--http--> Server